# How to deal with strings as values in functions?

Tags: r, string, function, ggplot2

I find it hard to formulate a question that fits, so I illustrate my problem in an example. I'd like to create similar plots for multiple variables in my dataset with a specific function. The function creates a summary data frame and produces a plot.

So without a function I would do the following, using the summarySE() function ([source](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/#Helper%20functions))

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

#data
df <- data.frame(case=rep(1:5,3),
                 value=rnorm(15))

#summarise
df_sum <- summarySE(df, "value", groupvars=c("case"))

#plot
ggplot(df_sum, aes(x=case, y=value)) +
  geom_point()
```

Now I tried to write a function that takes a data frame and a variable in that data frame and produces the plot above.

```
#function reproducing a nonsensical plot
f <- function(data,var){
  data_sum <- summarySE(data, var, groupvars=c("case"))
  x <- ggplot(data_sum, aes(x=case, y=var)) +
    geom_point()
  return(x)
}

f(df,"value")
```

I thought I could benefit from the fact, that the summarised variable in df_sum is named the same as the variable in df. But because ggplot() takes the string that I called in f(), it produces a nonsensical plot.

Does someone have a general solution how to adress problems like that? It is not the first time I ran into this type of problem with strings used as input in a function. I tried unquote() and similar things but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aes_string` here which accepts string arguments instead of `aes` but that is being deprecated.  A better way is to use tidy evaluation with `sym`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rlang)

f <- function(data,var) {
   data_sum <- Rmisc::summarySE(data, var, groupvars=c("case"))
   x <- ggplot(data_sum, aes(x=case, y=!!sym(var))) +  geom_point()
   return(x)
}

f(df,"value")
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thank you for the reply! It all works out now.